# "Absorbed in" vs. "absorbed with"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions

> That young man was absorbed **in** his big camera. He was shooting a short movie of people and passers by who were singing and reading the poems under the trees.

If I use *with* instead of *in*, does it change the meaning?

Comment: Yes, "with" postulates the existence of a new particle in order to explain how both the young man and his big camera can be absorbed.

Comment: What are you trying to say exactly? Are you trying to say that he is fully occupied by/with studying his camera or that he was somehow sucked into the camera?

Comment: I agree with Carlo_R.  If, on the other hand, the sentence were "That young man was absorbed in thought," then the word "with" would not fit before the word "thought."  It's as if the thought process sucked him into the thoughts inside his brain, and he momentarily lost awareness of the outside world around him.

Answer (score 2):

Answers to questions like this can be found fairly easily by looking in a few on-line dictionaries.

#### absorbed in

The following dictionary definitions and examples clearly show that this form is used when someone is engrossed in a pastime or other activity.

> **absorb** *verb [with object]* <sup>[1](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/absorb?q=absorbed) [selected extracts]</sup>
>   2. (often **be absorbed in**) take up the attention of (someone); interest greatly:
>   *she sat in an armchair, **absorbed in** a book*
>   *the work absorbed him and continued to make him happy*
>
> **absorb** *verb transitive* <sup>[2](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/absorb) [selected extracts]</sup>
>   3. [interest] to interest someone so much that they do not pay attention to other things:
>   *The movement and noise of the machines absorbed him completely.*
>   **be absorbed in something**
>   *Judith lay on the settee, **absorbed in** her book.*
>
> **absorbed** *adjective* <sup>[3](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/absorbed) [selected extracts]</sup>
>   *They were completely **absorbed in** each other.*
>   *There sat Magdalen, ... **absorbed in** the study of her part ...*

#### absorbed into

This form is used when one substance or entity becomes part of (is subsumed into) a larger entity.

> **absorb** *verb [with object]* <sup>[1](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/absorb?q=absorbed) [selected extracts]</sup>
>   1. take in or soak up (energy or a liquid or other substance) by chemical or physical action:
>   *steroids are **absorbed into** the bloodstream*
>   take control of (a smaller or less powerful entity) and make it a part of a larger one:
>   *the family firm was **absorbed into** a larger group*
>
> **absorb** *verb transitive* <sup>[2](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/absorb) [selected extracts]</sup>
>   1. [liquid/gas] to take in liquid, gas, or another substance from the surface or space around something:
>   **absorb something into something**
>   *Water and salts are absorbed into our blood stream.*
>   4. [become part of something] to become part of something larger:
>   **be absorbed into something**
>   *We were soon **absorbed into** local village life.*

#### absorbed with

I did not find this form in any of the dictionaries I consulted, which suggets that its usage is not common. I did, however, find the following examples of its usage <sup>[4](http://www.reference.com/browse/absorbed+with) [selected extracts]</sup>

> *... neutrons may then be **absorbed with** an isotope which has high affinity for slow neutrons ...*

The above example could probably alternatively use *absorbed by*.

> *ISP **absorbed with** new sun care filter.*
>   *House Sergeant at Arms **Absorbed With** Security*
>   *GUCCI'S CREATIVE DIRECTOR IS **ABSORBED WITH** INNOVATION AND RISK-TAKING.*

The above three examples are unusual usages, and might be regarded as similar to the use of *absorbed in*. There would seem to be a nuance of difference, however, in that *engrossed in* (as for *absorbed in*) would perhaps be too strong.  Perhaps a suitable meaning here is *fully occupied by/with*.

Comment: This is worth a look: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=absorbed+with%2Cabsorbed+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cabsorbed%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cabsorbed%20in%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cabsorbed%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cabsorbed%20in%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

When you say "absorbed in his big camera" you're saying that his focus is solely on his camera.

When you say "absorbed with his big camera" it sounds odd to my ear. It's like he's doing something he's absorbed in and the camera is along for the ride but the focus is more on him being absorbed than the camera.

One distinction is that "absorbed in" usually means you're in contact with it right now. But you can be absorbed with something in a more abstract way, or not in the current moment.

Here's a couple examples from some headlines I saw on the internet.

```
The SEC is not viewing porn: SEC Absorbed With Porn During Economic Crisis

Her daughter may not be listening to music now: My daughter is totally
absorbed with what she calls "alternative music."
```

Except for these exceptions, "absorbed in" is much more commonly used. You find dozens of links if you search google with:

```
site:english.stackexchange.com "absorbed in"
```

You only find your post if you search google with:

```
site:english.stackexchange.com "absorbed with"
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct, original usage is "absorbed in", but does that mean that where "absorbed **in**" isn't appropriate, you should look for another expression to use, other than absorbed?

I think that's being too careful. Without any authority to pull, I would say that using "our ears" as authority can be misleading. To my ears, it doesn't sound so much off. I think the expression should be useful also when you can't use **in**. Like in the two examples @dcaswell uses above. I'd love to be able to point out that the SEC makes bad use of language, but in general it would be the same snotty impulse when I tell anyone else that "absorbed with" is bad language, showing off that you know better.

It has to do with your approach to language, and mine is more flexible and less monolithic. Language evolves, and I can't see any special reason for preservation in this case. Does it work? I think so. Is it grating? I don't see why it should.